# Trying to find shortest distance from point $(2,0-3)$ to $x+y+z=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find shortest distance from the point $(2,0-3)$ to $x+y+z=1$.

I found $d^2=(x-2)^2+y^2+(z+3)^2$

Substituting for $z$: $d^2=(x-2)^2+y^2+(-x-y+1+3)^2$

$f_x=2x-4-2(-x-y+4)$ and $f_y=2y-2(-x-y+4)$ Next would be finding zeros as the critical points and using them as the $xyz$ values in the formula for $d$ but I'm having issues finding those points.

Comment: Why? You need to solve $2x-4+2x+2y-8=0$ and $2y+2x+2y-8=0$. Looks like a system of 2 equations. On a separate note, this problem can of course also be done without calculus, nut nonetheless a good exercise.

Comment: Why what? And yes, in those forms or the ones I wrote, I'm trying to solve for each of them equaling 0. That's where I'm having trouble. Because the x and y values that make one of them zero have to make the other zero as far I know.

Comment: Yes, that is true. When you solve the system of equations I revealed earlier, you will find exactly that combination $x$ and $y$. It comes down to the system $4x+2y=12$ with $2x+4y=8$. Can you solve this system?

Comment: ......after staring at it trying for ten minutes..... apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $4x+2y=12$ and $2x+4y=8$. First equation reduces to $y=6-2x$. Plugging that into the second gives $2x+4(6-2x)=8$ which solves to $2x+24-8x=8$ or $x=8/3$. Plugging this answer into $y=6-2x$ yields $y=2/3$. This is one of the many ways to solve such a system. Anyway, with this info you can find $z$ and from here you can find the shortest distance.

Comment: Ohh. Ok. Solve for one var in one substitute into the other and go back to the first equation... got it. I do kind of remember that from something a long time ago. Thanks a lot. I have a bunch of these problems and I starting to go a bit crazy over this part of them.

Comment: Solving systems of equations is indeed important as you want both partial derivatives to be equal to zero. Mind you, there are more complicated problems that this one, because this one turned out all linear. It won't stay like that...Anyway, when stuck again, post another one. Show some steps to show effort and we can get you an answer.